# Does there exist a leaf of this holomorphic foliation with non trivial holonomy?

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Let's $\mathcal{F}$ be the holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ tangent to the kernel of $\alpha=(sin x) dx -(cos x)dy$.

> Are all leaves of $\mathcal{F}$ simply connected? If the answer is no, does there exist a leaf with non trivial holonomy?

Comment: No and no. The leaves are the level sets of the function $e^ycosx$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie  Thank you. Is it obvious that the connected components of level sets  correspond to non zero values $c\neq 0$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: On the contrary, for each complex number $a$ such that $cos a=0$ there is the leaf $x=a$, but each other leaf is the graph of a branch of the function $y=-log(cos x)$, and is therefore an infinite cyclic cover of the set of all $x\in\mathbb C$ such that $cos x\neq 0$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie I am sorry if I change my question on this system as follows: let's consider the same $1$-form but as a real form on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the foliation would be foliation by geodesic?

Comment: This seems like an unrelated question, now, but yes: let $u=e^ycosx$, let $v=e^ysinx $, let the metric be $ds^2=du^2+dv^2$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Lately, you have been performing a lot of minor needless edits on old, inactive posts, with a low view count. This bumps them to the main page, a thing that MO users don't like. Please stop doing this.

Comment: @AlexM.  Thank you for your comment. I  do not see any edit on this post. may be you are talking on some other post. I  am sorry if  I  did  needles edit but i belive  "needless" is  not  absolute concept, it is  a  relative concept. Any  way i had  a  suggestion for  bumping MINOR (but not necessarily needless) edits to the  main page. Please reed he  following meta post https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2749/how-to-discourage-excessive-self-edits/2751#2751